# SetWindowsHookEx can't hook specific application repeatedly

Tags: c++, hook, setwindowshookex

I want to use the SetWindowsHookEx() to get user's key pressed and mouse clicked.
And I have defined a global keyboard/mouse hook and install it with SetWindowsHookEx. 
The hooks works on almost application, but it can't work on specific application (e.g. Cain & Abel).

#### The problem is:

**When the first time I clicked Cain & Abel, I can get the click information. Then it can't work until I click another application or console.**

Here is part of my code:

```
    #include <QtCore/QCoreApplication>
    #include <QtDebug>
    #include <QTime>
    #include <QChar>
    #include <iostream>
    #include <Windows.h>
    #pragma comment(lib, "user32.lib")

    HHOOK hHook = NULL;
    HHOOK hMouseHook = NULL;
```

Main:

```
    int main(int argc, char *argv[])
    {

        QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);
        HINSTANCE hInstance = GetModuleHandle(NULL);

        hHook = SetWindowsHookEx(WH_KEYBOARD_LL, MyLowerLevelKeyBoardProc, NULL, 0);
        hMouseHook = SetWindowsHookEx(WH_MOUSE_LL, MyLowerLevelMouseProc, hInstance, 0);

        MSG message;
        while (GetMessage(&message,NULL,0,0)) {
            TranslateMessage( &message );
            DispatchMessage( &message );
        }

        UnhookWindowsHookEx(hHook);
        UnhookWindowsHookEx(hMouseHook);


        if (hHook == NULL || hMouseHook == NULL)
        {
            qDebug() << "Hook failed";
        }

        return a.exec();
    }
```

Callback function: MyLowerLevelMouseProc

```
    LRESULT CALLBACK MyLowerLevelMouseProc(int nCode, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam){
MOUSEHOOKSTRUCT *pMouseStruct = (MOUSEHOOKSTRUCT *)lParam;

        if (pMouseStruct != NULL){
            POINT   screenpoint;
            HWND    hwndFoundWindow = NULL;

            switch(wParam){
                case WM_LBUTTONDOWN:
                    GetCursorPos (&screenpoint);
                    hwndFoundWindow = WindowFromPoint (screenpoint);
                    qDebug() << "1. Mouse click! (Left), x= " << screenpoint.x << ", y= " << screenpoint.y;
                    qDebug() << "2. hwndFoundWindow=" << hwndFoundWindow
                break;

                case WM_RBUTTONDOWN:
                    GetCursorPos (&screenpoint);
                    hwndFoundWindow = WindowFromPoint (screenpoint);
                    qDebug() << "Mouse click! (Right)" ;
                break;

            }

        }
        return CallNextHookEx(hMouseHook, nCode, wParam, lParam);
    }
```

If there are any ideas and solutions, please help me.
Thanks a lot.

Comment: That mouse hook looks buggy - if the message it sees is `WM_RBUTTONDOWN`, isn't it using `screenpoint` that hasn't been set by anything?

Comment: Don't know if it's related to your problem, but if `dwThreadId` is 0, then `lpfn` must point to a function inside a DLL. As you have a `main()`, I suspect you are not using a DLL.

Comment: To Damien_The_Unbeliever:
Oops, that's my negligence. Thank you. I will edit it. But it doesn't influence the result of my question.

Comment: To jblume: I am not sure whether I use the DLL or not. (Maybe not)
Thanks for your hint, I will think about it in this direction.

Comment: Perhaps it's the 32bit/64bit issue. Hooks set by 32 bit applications can intercept messages by 32 bit applications only. Same for 64 bit. **Or** perhaps the app is setting hooks itself and doesn't call `CallNextHookEx`.

Comment: @W.B. : Thanks for your comment. But I don't know how to check my hooks is 32 bit or 64 bit. I just use the SetWindowHookEx. Could you give me more information? And if the reason is the app doesn't call     CallNextHookEx, is there a possible solution to deal with it?